# How do you click a button by its inner text in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of html code:

```
<div class ="listit">
  <a href="javascript:dB()">Update</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=5">New iso</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check></a>
</div>
```

The buttons look like that:
[image]

Now I like to press the button called **Update** by using its name (but I'm also very interested to see if it works without using its name).

I have already tried to go through the class and collect the names using loop:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("listit");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var counter = x[i].innerText;
  if(counter == "Update"){

  }
}
```

And I think I almost have it, I just could not find a working way to use that click() function so I click the button **Update** by name? There is not something like `document.getElementByInnerText()`? I don't know how to get this work..? :S

Comment: Your buttons do not have the `listit` class so your code will not work at all.

Comment: For semantics (especially accessibility), you should consider using buttons for buttons and not links as buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting the surrounding `div` (which actually has the CSS class `listit`), not the links inside it.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("listit");

console.log(x);
```

```html
<div class ="listit">
  <a href="javascript:dB()">Update</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=5">New iso</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check&gt;</a>
</div>
```

If you need a collection of the links, use `document.querySelectorAll('.listit a')`:

```js
function dB() {
  console.log('dB called');
}

const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.listit a'));

links.forEach((link) => {
  if (link.textContent === 'Update') {
    link.click();
  }
})
```

```html
<div class ="listit">
  <a href="javascript:dB()">Update</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=5">New iso</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check&gt;</a>
</div>
```

**Sidenote**: There are certain characters that need to be replaced by their so-called HTML entities to be usable inside HTML tag content, the most important being these:

```
&<>
```

So I replaced your

```
<a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check></a>
```

by

```
<a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check&gt;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the child elements too to get the button since your class selector works on the parent div.

This is really bad design though. If you have the ability to change the html please do so.

```js
var mainElement = document.getElementsByClassName("listit");
for (var i = 0; i < mainElement.length; i++) {
  var children = mainElement[i].childNodes;
  for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
    if (children[j].innerText == "Update") {
      console.log('found by innertext');
      console.log(children[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="listit">
  <a href="javascript:dB()">Update</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=5">New iso</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check></a>
</div>
```

You can even get the element by the `href` attribute if that's an options for you. Al tough this looks very dodgy too.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.listit a[href="javascript:dB()');
console.log(element);
```

```html
<div class="listit">
  <a href="javascript:dB()">Update</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=5">New iso</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check></a>
</div>
```

This is how the button works. By putting `javascript:` in the href the button executes the part of the `href` after the `:`. So in this case `dB()` which means execution of the function named `db`.

```js
function dB() {
  console.log('update button pressed');
}
```

```html
<div class="listit">
      <a href="javascript:dB()">Update</a>
      <a href="post.php?f=54&y=5">New iso</a>
      <a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is not my own html I was only visiting random sites and try to learn different ways to click buttons. This looked very crazy with the hrefs to me and I was curious how it was done here.

Comment: The `href` of the button you mention executes javascript when the button is pressed. When you press the button the function `dB()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a `mouseEvent` and use `dispatchEvent` to fire it.  (You also need to loop over `listit`'s children, rather than the div itself):

```js
var dB = function() {console.log("CLICKED")}

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("listit")[0].children;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var counter = x[i].innerText;
  if (counter == "Update") {
    x[i].dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent('click')
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="listit">
  <a href="javascript:dB()">Update</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=5">New iso</a>
  <a href="post.php?f=54&y=2">New check></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `div.listit` might have non-clickable children whose `innerText` is `Update`.

Comment: I suppose that's possible.   Firing a click event on a non-clickable child would be harmless, however. (This certainly isn't a traversal structure I would use, I was just avoiding modifying parts of their code that weren't directly relevant to the question they asked.)

Comment: Sure it is, but it's not intentional in those cases which is why it might be better to only target potential candidates for the collection to iterate over.